# need to fetch all elements after a specific element

Tags: xml, xpath

is there an XPath expression that would return all `<a>` elements that follow the `<span>` in the document below? That is: `[y,z]`.

`<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="x">x</a>
      <span>s</span>
      <a href="y">y</a>
      <a href="z">z</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//a[preceding-sibling::span]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//td/span/following-sibling::a
```